# SOAP module in Laravel project issue

Tags: php, web-services, soap, laravel-5

I'm trying to implement a consuming wsdl on a Laravel project

I'm trying to use [this - Laravel SoapClient Wrapper](https://github.com/artisaninweb/laravel-soap)

But I'm having a problem with this

```
// Add a new service to the wrapper
    SoapWrapper::add(function ($service) {
        $service
            ->name('getSessionKey')
            ->wsdl('somelink?wsdl');
            //->trace(true);                                                    // Optional: (parameter: true/false)
            //->header()                                                      // Optional: (parameters: $namespace,$name,$data,$mustunderstand,$actor)
            //->customHeader($customHeader)                                   // Optional: (parameters: $customerHeader) Use this to add a custom SoapHeader or extended class
            //->cookie()                                                      // Optional: (parameters: $name,$value)
            //->location()                                                    // Optional: (parameter: $location)
            //->certificate()                                                 // Optional: (parameter: $certLocation)
            //->cache(WSDL_CACHE_NONE)                                        // Optional: Set the WSDL cache
            //->options(['UserLogin' => 'username', 'Password' => 'password']);   // Optional: Set some extra options
    });

    $createSession = [
        'UserLogin' => 'Thelogin',
        'Password'   => 'Thepassword',
    ];

    // Using the added service
    SoapWrapper::service('CreateSession', function ($service) use ($createSession) {
        var_dump($service->call('CreateSession', [$createSession])->SessionCreate);
    });
```

The webservice I'm trying to call is called 'createSession', is header less and receives a username and password and returns a session key

EDIT: my question is : why isn't this working? I'm getting the error

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'thelink' : failed to load external entity "thelink"
```

what's wrong? How does this work?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: what is the simplest way to implement a soap client? I'm completely and utterly lost in this... I was given the SOAP UI files that implement the webservices... I'm not sure what's the easiest ways to impleemtn.

Comment: did you get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

In you soapwrapper you name your service

> $service->name('getSessionKey')

but when using it your referring to

> SoapWrapper::service('CreateSession',

1. either rename your service to CreateSession like so

   $service->name('CreateSession ')

**or**

2. rename your call like so to getSessionKey

> SoapWrapper::service('getSessionKey',